# Strange Upload Issue

Tags: codeigniter, upload

I have a file upload issue.

I have done 777 via ftp and file manager

drwxrwxrwx 2 user user 4096 Apr 10 08:56 gallery/
drwxrwxrwx 2 user user 4096 Apr 10 10:30 sales/

I have echoed the `$file_info` and the location shows as correct but the file is not uploading:

```
//Set File Settings 
$config['upload_path'] = 'includes/uploads/gallery/'; 
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png'; 
$config['max_size'] = '100'; 
$config['max_width'] = '1024'; 
$config['max_height'] = '768'; 

$this->load->library('upload', $config); 
$this->upload->do_upload();
$file_info = $this->upload->data();

$data = array(   
    'description' => $this->input->post('description', TRUE), 
    'path' => $file_info['file_name'] 
    ); 

$this->image_model->addImage($data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by a slow connection uploading to a server.  I tried on another connection and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please check write permissions? If you're using linux check also prefs of SELinux.